# Splunk email error

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, splunk

I have been getting a Splunk error for the following Splunk query:

```
| savedsearch "Logs" | stats count | sendemail to=test@user.com
```

**Error**:

> command="sendemail", 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' while sending mail to: test@user.com

Does anyone know of what is the root cause of this? I am using AWS SES Email service configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your email address.  It should look like this:

```
| savedsearch "Logs" | stats count | sendemail to="test@user.com"
```

See Splunk's [sendemail docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.1/SearchReference/Sendemail) for more information.